# jdbcTemplate.query works fine when passing few parameters and doesn't work for others

Tags: sql, oracle, jdbctemplate

I have a select Oracle SQL that I am hitting using jdbcTemplate.query method. This returns a bean of the values from the table. I am passing a dynamic value to the query that will be used in the WHERE clause. However, the SQL values for few values that i am passing. But when I pass the value as NA it won't work. Any suggestions on this or help me with what am i missing?

```
private static final String regionSearchSql = "SELECT PRFLID, PRFLNM, RGN_CD FROM %PREFIX%MER_PRFL WHERE RGN_CD = ?"; 

public List<SearchProfileBean> regionSearchProfile(SearchProfileRequest searchProfileRequest) throws DatabaseQueryException {
        try {
            return jdbcTemplate.query((QueryUtility.getQueryWithPrefix(regionSearchSql,prefix)), new SearchProfileRowMapper(), searchProfileRequest.getRegionName());

        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new DatabaseQueryException(QueryUtility.getQueryWithPrefix(regionSearchSql, prefix), e);
        }
    }
```

If i pass 'EMEA', 'LAC', 'JAPA' in searchProfileRequest.getRegionName() - the SQL returns perfect results. But if I pass 'NA' in searchProfileRequest.getRegionName(), it gives empty results. But there are rows in the table for NA.

Comment: Are you sure you don't have a mismatch in trailing whitespace between the table values and variable? Or uncommitted data?

Comment: @AlexPoole - Yes. There was some trailing spaces after NA on the table. Thanks for pointing that. Apparently thats how the table is setup.